# PHP generate tree array from array list

Tags: php, arrays

I want to manage my array but I haven't got idea how I should to do it.

My basic array

```
$table = array(
        'color' => array('white', 'red'),
        'size' => array('37', '38'),
        'other' => array('a', 'b'),
    );
```

What I want to return:

```
$table = array(
            'color' => array(
                'white' => array(
                    'size' => array(
                        '37' => array(
                            'other' => array('a', 'b')
                        ),
                        '38' => array(
                            'other' => array('a', 'b')
                        ),
                    )
                ),
                'red' => array(
                    'size' => array(
                        '37' => array(
                            'other' => array('a', 'b')
                        ),
                        '38' => array(
                            'other' => array('a', 'b')
                        ),
                    )
                )
            )
        );
```

It's only a simple table, I want to create a code which will render 2nd or 4th tables.
I hope that someone can help me.
I know that how many keys in table that many depths.

Comment: Please show something you have tried.

Comment: Some code would be nice.

Answer (score 0):

You can use nested `foreach` loops to accomplish what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution of your Problem:

```
$table = array(
        'color' => array('white', 'red'),
        'size' => array('37', '38'),
        'other' => array('a', 'b'),
    );

function myfunc($table){    
    foreach($table as $k=>$v){
        if($k == 'color'){
            foreach($v as  $color){
                $result['color'][$color]= array() ;
            }
        }elseif($k == 'size'){
            foreach($v as $size){
                foreach($result['color'] as $colorKey => $colorName){
                    $result['color'][$colorKey]['size'][$size] = $table['other']; 
                }
            }
        }           
    }
    return $result;
}
    $result = myfunc($table);

    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($result);
```

Out put:

[image]